# explain output from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

output of this program comes as "Inside Thread Inside Thread" , How this is happening?

```
class MyThread extends Thread 
{ 
    MyThread() {} 
    MyThread(Runnable r) {super(r); } 
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.print("Inside Thread ");
    } 
} 
class MyRunnable implements Runnable 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.print(" Inside Runnable"); 
    } 
} 
class ThreadRunnableBoth 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        new MyThread().start();
        new MyThread(new MyRunnable()).start(); 
    } 
}
```

I can understand how first "Inside Thread" is printing but for second time print I am expecting to print "Inside Runnable" but it prints "Inside Thread" , how this is happening ?
Please explain .....thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run()` method of `java.lang.Thread` simply calls `target.run()`, where `target` is the `Runnable` provided during construction. However, in `MyThread`, you've overridden this functionality; your version of `run()` ignores the target and prints "Inside Thread" instead.

One way to fix it is to run your `Runnable` with an instance of the base `Thread` class:

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

Other possibilities would be *not* to override `run()`, or to call `super.run()` from your override.

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyThread` class you are overriding the `run()` method.  That means that even though you are passing in the `Runnable` into the constructor, only *your* run method will be called and the `Runnable` target will be ignored.

Here's the `Thread.run()` method code that you are overriding:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

If you want to use your runnable I'd do:

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

That does not use the `MyThread` class.

Answer (score 1):

The `run` method in `Thread` is defined as follows:

```
public void run() {
  if (target != null) {
    target.run();
  }
}
```

Because you've overridden `run` in `MyThread`, it won't actually call your `MyRunnable`.

To get the behaviour you're expecting:

```
new MyThread().start();
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new MyThread().start();
```

In this case, Thread is created calling the run() method of MyThread class through MyThread() {} constructer.

In the 2nd case, thread is created calling run() method of the same MyThread class through MyThread(Runnable) constructer.

Answer (score 0):

change the second call to Thread:

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start
```

because your custom thread override the run method that will be called even after you passing your runnable to thread constructor.